# Can't use survey_mean in sapply

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using survey data with packages `survey` and `srvyr` and I have some trouble applying `survey_mean()` to all columns.

Here's an example:

```
library(survey)
library(srvyr)

data(api)

dstrata <- apistrat %>%
  as_survey_design(strata = stype, weights = pw) %>%
  mutate(api00 = ifelse(api00 == 467, NA, api00),
         api99 = ifelse(api99 == 491, NA, api99))

sapply(dstrata$variables %>% select(api99, api00), function(x){
  x <- enquo(x)
  dstrata %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!x)) %>%
    summarise(stat = srvyr::survey_mean(!!x, na.rm = TRUE)[, 1]) 
})
```

> Error: Assigned data `x` must be compatible with existing data.
>   x Existing data has 198 rows.
>   x Assigned data has 200 rows.
>   ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
>   Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Note that:

```
dstrata %>%
  select(api99, api00) %>%
  summarise_all(.funs = srvyr::survey_mean, na.rm = T)
```

works with this example but not with my actual data so I would like to understand why the function above does not work.

I'm using `srvyr_0.3.9` and `survey_4.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why would you need any kind of NSE here because in `sapply` only the value is passed and not an expression.

This seems to work :

```
library(dplyr)

sapply(dstrata$variables %>% select(api99, api00), function(x){
   dstrata %>%
      summarise(stat = srvyr::survey_mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) 
})

#        api99    api00   
#stat    630.3107 663.4118
#stat_se 10.14777 9.566393
```